# Phaser.ScaleManager.RESIZE; has no canvas size limit

Tags: html5-canvas, scale, phaser-framework, window-resize

Noob here using Phaser. But here's my issue:

I'm struggling to get the perfect scale for the game I'm building. The best option for me so far is Phaser.ScaleManager.RESIZE;
But this method doesn't have a limit to the canvas size. If an user has a huge screen, say 30 inches, he'd have a lot of advantage over an user with a medium size screen, say 17 inches. The 30 inches user would have much more view of the world.

I've tried to set the canvas to a fixed size, like 1280x720, then dynamically resize the canvas style. And using Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL; But it doesn't do the trick because it shows the black borders and I can't get rid of it.

To make it clear what I want to achieve, I'm building an online multiplayer game (.io). If you notice the most famous .io games like agar.io, diep.io and slither.io, the game scale is perfect for any screen size. If the screen is too big, the game doesn't show more screen. It just adjusts for a more zoomed game.

Here's a gif of what I need and how my game is now:

agar.io:
https://gyazo.com/94a41e06816b8dc9a1fd4608c0cfa525

Notice that in agario, the screen only goes so far before the game starts to scale.

My game:
https://gyazo.com/4269ecfb1253b9ddbcd6e917ad1a8602

Notice how much of the world I can see after scaling the game. Meaning that there is no limit for the canvas size. That's bad.

Please let me know if you need more information in order to help me out here!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like it's not a scaling problem but a camera problem. What does the camera do when you squish the window like this?

Comment: It does like you see on the Gif. It shows more of the game area. It might have something to do with camera. But I'm not sure though. If that's the case, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try taking a look at `game.camera.width` and `game.camera.height` before and after the resize.